# detect output stream on linux shell script

Tags: bash, shell, stream, output

I'm trying write a shell scrip on linux to detect a string on output steam.

This is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
./binary
```

binary file is compiled from source file as below:

```
gcc-4.6 main.c -o binary 

//main.c
#include "stdio.h"
void main(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
       printf("data: %d\n", i);
       sleep(1);  // delay 1s
    }
}
```

Could you let me know how to detect "data: 10" from output ./binary?

Comment: What do you want to do when you detect it? Might be as simple as `./binary | while read line; do if test "$line" = 'data: 10'; then do_whatever; fi; done`.

Comment: In *ALL* the output at once, or line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `stdout` is not connected to a terminal, it's fully buffered by default. So if you want to be able to detect output immediately (as suggested by the `sleep(1);` in the code) you need to flush the buffer after printing.

```
#include "stdio.h"
void main(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
        printf("data: %d\n", i);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);  // delay 1s
    }
}
```

Then you can pipe the output of the program to something in the script and it will detect the output without waiting for the program to finish.

Comment: it seem fine with me. I can write to file without wating command finish. Could you explain how to use pipe the output on shell scrip? I want use pipe to check instead of write to file